# Вылетает с исключением "... файл используется другим процессом" c#

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

```
string path = "M&M/" + provSurname + ".txt";
if (File.Exists(path) == false)
{
    File.Create(path);
}
StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(path); //Открываем файл для чтения
```

Последняя строка - вылетает исключение, как это возможно (вылетает только если он создается, если он был ранее создан проблем нет)

Comment: Вангую, вы не закрыли предыдущий `StreamReader` на тот же файл.

Comment: Эм.. Но зачем открывать на чтение только что созданный файл?

Comment: @VladD, Qwertiy дежавю какое-то

Comment: @VladD, он написал, что после создания - в таком случае там нет другого streamreader'а.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Чёта мне не верится в чудеса :)

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил

Comment: @Vyacheslav, [в примере MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx) почти ваш код

Answer (score 4):

[File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает `FileStream` для только что созданного файла.

Так как вы его не закрываете получаете свою ошибку.

Один из вариантов, не закрывать этот поток, а сразу читать из него, что-то вроде

```
StreamReader streamReader;
string path = "M&M/" + provSurname + ".txt";
if (File.Exists(path) == false)
{
    streamReader = new StreamReader(File.Create(path));
}else{
    streamReader = File.OpenText(path); //Открываем файл для чтения
}
```

Comment: `new StreamReader(File.Create(path))` - это точно нормально?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще говоря не пробовал :-) но `Create` возвращает ` `FleStream` который можно передать в конструктор StreamReader'а :-) так что думаю нормально

Comment: @Qwertiy, хотя конечно смысла что-то не видно :-) читать из пустого файла можно но результат вроде заранее известен:)

Comment: Но у `Stream` есть свойство `CanRead`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я потерял нить разговора :)

Comment: Вроде не любой поток можно читать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, надо попробовать

Comment: @Qwertiy, В общем попробовал - нормально создает файл, поток, стримреадер, значение `ReadToEnd` - пустая строка.

Comment: Значит всё-таки работает эта странная конструкция :) Хотя с using'ом тут не очень хорошо получается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36361/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680284/system-io-file-create-locking-a-file

`File.Create` возвращает поток, который можно использовать, например, так:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    ...
}
```

В твоём случае, так:

```
File.Create(path).Close()
```

А вообще, советую подумать, зачем вообще открывать пустой файл для чтения.

Comment: Наверняка у `File.OpenText` есть перегрузка, которая умеет создавать файл, если надо.

Comment: @VladD, не, у `File.OpenText` нет, Но есть `CreateText` который как раз создает или открывает